# Is it possible to have a higher level of lock-screen security only on boot up?

Tags: lock-screens, security

Many of my apps are protected by an lock app ('Smart Applock' - asking for a pattern unlock before access to gMail, install/uninstall, etc). As most of my apps are thus locked individually, I would like to have the convenience of a swipe-only unlock during normal use ... however, none of the app-locking apps I have tried offer protection just after boot-up! While the various bits of the system are loading, one can still access, say, gMail, and other functions for ~ 30 seconds.

To get around this problem of reduced security during the startup process, I was wondering if it would be possible to have a pattern or password unlock requested by the system *once* only, after boot?

Edit: one suggestion is to disable the 'power button instantly locks' and the automatic lock after sleep, which would mean that a password/pattern is asked on startup only and never thereafter. However, for the lock after sleep all one can do is select a time up to **30 minutes**, not disable the auto-lock after sleep entirely. Is there a hack to extend or remove that limit?

Comment: Is your device set to lock when the screen turns off? If you can disable that then the initial unlock request should be the only one unless you manually lock it.

Comment: Good suggestion - but there is still a _timed_ lock that happens, and the maximum I could set is 30 minutes. Perhaps there's a setting I could set (in terminal) to remove that timed lock?

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt your phone and it then will ask for a pin each time you boot your phone

Comment: Actually this is seriously counter-productive. After encryption, swipe is totally disabled and the device asks for a pin code every time you use it.